# Postgres count(*) extremely slowly

Tags: postgresql, performance, count

I know that count(*) in Postgres is generally slow, however I have a database where it's super slow. I'm talking about minutes even hours.

There is approximately 40M rows in a table and the table consists of 29 columns (most of the are text, 4 are double precision). There is an index on one column which should be unique and I've already run `vacuum full`. It took around one hour to complete but without no observable results.

Database uses dedicated server with 32GB ram. I set `shared_buffers` to 8GB and `work_mem` to 80MB but no speed improvement. I'm aware there are some techniques to get approximated count or to use external table to keep the count but I'm not interested in the count specifically, I'm more concerned about performance in general, since now it's awful. When I run the count there are no CPU peeks or something. Could someone point where to look? Can it be that data are structured so badly that 40M rows are too much for postgres to handle?

Comment: Is there an index on whatever fields are mentioned in the `WHERE` clause of your `SELECT COUNT(*)` query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: VACUUM FULL does not set the visibility map, it destroys it.  Run a plain VACUUM.